# Getting error in [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory when using CompressionLevel of SmallestSize

Tags: powershell, compression

I want to compress a directory using PowerShell script. The following script works when I set the compression level to be Optimal or Fastest, but it is failing with SmallestSize.

```
$compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::SmallestSize
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory("testfolder","D:\Dev.zip", $compressionLevel, $false)
```

Error:

```
Cannot find an overload for "CreateFromDirectory" and the argument count: "4".
At line:1 char:1
+ [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory("testfolder","D: ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

The same script is working if I set compression level as Optimal/Fastest -
`$compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal`

Comment: I'm assuming you're using PowerShell Core. I'm unable to replicate the error. Works fine in 7.3-preview.

Comment: `SmallestSize` might not be available for your PowerShell version (Not 5.1 or lower). Run `[System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]  | Get-Member -Static -MemberType Property` to check.

Comment: @jfrmilner I think you're totally right and the only explanation I can find to the error. You should post it as an answer. OP is likely using .NET Framework and `[System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::SmallestSize` evaluates to null.

Comment: I always liked the syntax of `[enum]::GetNames([System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel])` better than piping a type to `Get-Member` for getting enums like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SmallestSize` is not available and will evaluate as null if your PowerShell version is 5.1 or lower.

If you'd like to check what options you have available, you can run the following command:

`[System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel] | Get-Member -Static -MemberType Property`